# leaflet markers non shown on ios mobile device

Tags: leaflet

I use leaflet to display my geolocated picture on my website (you can see my test site here: http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/pages/map-osm/)

everthing goes fine exept one thing:
when I browse my website from an ios mobile device (ios 11.3.1), no markers are displayed.

I can't figure where is the matter.

I try to have a reduce test case (only html, outside zenphoto, used for my gallery) with only 2 markers but the issue remains the same.
You can see it here:

http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/test_osm_map.html

can you point me to the right direction to solve this issue?

thanks for your help!!
vincent

**edit after comment:**
there is the code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/zp-core/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/zp_openstreetmap.css" />
    <script src="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
    <title>[VB] Photo US | Map OSM</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>Map OSM</h3>
    <div id="osm_map" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('osm_map', {
            zoom: 4,
            zoomControl: false,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 18
        });
        L.tileLayer.provider('OpenTopoMap').addTo(map);
        L.control.zoom({position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([57.150,-6.100]).addTo(map);
        L.marker([57.500,-6.450]).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds([
            [57.150,-6.100], [57.500,-6.450]
        ]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In order for us to help with your code, you need to share the code....

Answer (score 0):

there is the code of my test case taht you can see here: http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/test_osm_map.html

I am unable to see the 2 markers on my ios mobile device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/zp-core/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/zp_openstreetmap.css" />
    <script src="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/plugins/zp_openstreetmap/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
    <title>[VB] Photo US | Map OSM</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>Map OSM</h3>
    <div id="osm_map" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('osm_map', {
            zoom: 4,
            zoomControl: false,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 18
        });
        L.tileLayer.provider('OpenTopoMap').addTo(map);
        L.control.zoom({position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([57.150,-6.100]).addTo(map);
        L.marker([57.500,-6.450]).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds([
            [57.150,-6.100], [57.500,-6.450]
        ]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should **edit** your question in order to add further details, instead of using an _answer_, if it does not provide a solution.

Comment: sorry,
I will remember for the next question.
Is there a way to help me?

Comment: Thx for having moved your content to your question. Sorry I do not have an iOS device currently. It would also help if you could provide a live reproduction example on a service like JSFiddle, Plunker, etc. instead of your own server that can change content any time, making your post useless to future readers. Use CDN version of Leaflet.